# Is there any option to grab to more Views without ViewGroups?

Tags: android, xml, viewgroup

In Android you can select one view with "id", but is there any option to select more views (like "group" in CSS)?

For example, I want to select the **View** *and* the **TextView**, without using an extra LayoutView.
Is there any `Group-Tag`? or is there any other option to use the id more than once?

```
<View
        android:id="@+id/cardFront"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="407dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/image"
/>
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/string2"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find multiple ids in a single java statement. You need to put an extra parent to both the views. To select both your `View` and the `TextView`, you can keep both of them in a [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html) and then try finding it by id.

Answer (score 0):

Ids can be duplicated without any harm as long as you are aware of that. If you don't want to use ids, there are tags:

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/cardFront"
    android:tag="myTag"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="407dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/image"
/>
<TextView
    android:tag="myTag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/string2"
/>
```

By default there's no method to get more than one view, but it's pretty easy:

```
public List<View> findViewsById(int id) {
    List<View> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ViewGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    groups.add(this);
    while (!groups.isEmpty()) {
        ViewGroup group = groups.remove(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (child.getId() == id)
                result.add(child);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup)
                groups.add((ViewGroup) child);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

public List<View> findViewsWithTag(Object tag) {
    List<View> result = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ViewGroup> groups = new ArrayList<>();
    groups.add(this);
    while (!groups.isEmpty()) {
        ViewGroup group = groups.remove(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < group.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = group.getChildAt(i);
            if (tag.equals(child.getTag()))
                result.add(child);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup)
                groups.add((ViewGroup) child);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Woot, I thought the question was asked now. It was the edit